# ascii decimal to character using jq

Tags: ascii, data-conversion, jq

What's the best way to read and convert a JSON field's decimal value to an ASCII character?  For instance, converting 107 to 'k'.  The manual doesn't appear to mention a direct way to do so.

Comment: I am not very familiar with JSON, but this is a classic use of reinterpret cast. Basically, you store the data as a byte then reinterpret it as a character since 107 in binary is k. In c it looks like this `char c = *((char *)&((byte)(107)));` Here I took the pointer to where 107 is stored in memory, reinterpreted the pointer as a character pointer, then dereferenced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ jq -n '[107] | implode'
"k"
```

`implode` will work for both ASCII and non-ASCII decimal codes.  As illustrated here, it converts an array of admissible decimals to a UTF-8 string equivalent.

Here's an example showing conversion:

```
$ jq -n -c '{"a": [107, 108]} | .a |= implode'
{"a":"kl"}
```

Comment: thanks! i probably missed that in the docs because i was searching on "ascii".